# Who is God of relationship?

Tags: gods, karma, stotra, human, samsara

```
 खलसहवासं विघटय सतामेव सङ्गमनिशं भो ।
सांब सदाशिव शंभो शङ्कर शरणं मे तव चरणयुगम ॥ १७॥

Oh Lord  break  my relation with evil  people  
and always make me  in company  of good people

Oh Samba , Sadhashiva, Oh Shambu, Oh  Sankara,
I surrender  to the pair of  your feet
```

I want be surrounded by Good People, OR be in relationship with Good People OR have Good relationship with People (Confused)

any Text or portion of Text, Verses similar to one above..

talk about,

- how to pick good people among the crowd, to make friends with,
- how to handle relations, not to get caught among bad people, and get
  pulled in bad stuffs..
- what determines, unchosen relationships like Parents, Siblings,Cousins
- Which god, handle/controls, Human to Human relationship-interactions..etc
- Or Verses similar to above one, to simply chant

Comment: Love relationship only has god called Kamadev. Friends, parents and children, siblings, guru shishya etc not sure.

Answer (score 1):

**Mitra**

> According to britannica.com

Mitra, in the pantheon of Vedic Hinduism, one of the gods in the category of Adityas, sovereign principles of the universe. He represents friendship, integrity, harmony, and all else that is important in the successful maintenance of order in human existence

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism community. We try to use original scriptures as source of Hinduism, instead of secondary sources. Would you be able to cite a scripture containing similar details? That'd be greatly helpful. Thanks.